# Updating Chartjs-node-canvas to support Chart.js 4.X

Tags: chart.js

I am working on updating the following library to support Chart.js 4.X:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/chartjs-node-canvas

I am not the original author of this library. Currently, I am getting the following error:
TypeError: this._chartJs is not a constructor

I believe the line of code in the library causing this error is:
const chart = new this._chartJs(context, configuration);

For reference this is how _chartJs is defined:
private readonly _chartJs: typeof ChartJS

Does anyone have a suggestion how to fix this? In general, is there a strategy utilizing the 4.x migration guide to find all potential breaking changes in this library? Thank you the help!

So far, I tried to use the library as is, but it threw the error above.  I'm not familiar with using chart.js directly to create a chart object as I have always used the library above.

Answer (score 0):

I had been looking for a solution as well and recently on the ChartjsNodeCanvas Github project under an ongoing discussion thread a contributor posted a solution to working with Canvas and Chart.js directly within a project and bypassing ChartjsNodeCanvas altogether. It took a bit of experimenting to get it working correctly but I have now moved all projects out of ChartjsNodeCanvas and am using Chart.js 4.4.0. For the basics, you need to require or import the dependencies:

```
const { Chart } = require("chart.js/auto");
const { createCanvas } = require("canvas");
```

Next you need to setup various Chart.js options. In my case I use a plugin that is in node_modules and I also have a small plugin for setting the canvas background color that I extracted from ChartjsNodeCanvas:

```
Chart.register(
  require("chartjs-plugin-datalabels"),
  {
    id: "BackgroundColor",
    beforeDraw: (chart) => {
      const { ctx } = chart;
      ctx.save();
      ctx.fillStyle = BackgroundColor;
      ctx.fillRect(0, 0, chart.canvas.width, chart.canvas.height);
      ctx.restore();
    }
  }
);
```

Finally there is the actual rendering of the chart. If migrating from Chart.js 3.x.x, some configuration options may have changed. With a radar chart, I had some minor property changes to make as the names had changed. Also, I found that "maintainAspectRatio: false" needed to be set under options. When I used ChartjsNodeCanvas this appeared to happen automatically (took a while to figure out why my charts looked so off). In my case, I was depending on async methods in ChartjsNodeCanvas to return either a data URL or a buffer so I had to wrap the canvas routines in Promises:

```
  const canvas = createCanvas(Width, Height);
  const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  const chart = new Chart(ctx, configuration);
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    canvas.toDataURL("image/png", (error, url) => {
      chart.destroy();
      if (error) {
        return reject(error);
      }
      return resolve(url);
    }, "image/png");
  });
```

For a buffer, I use the following:

```
  const canvas = createCanvas(Width, Height);
  const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  const chart = new Chart(ctx, configuration);
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    canvas.toBuffer((error, buffer) => {
      chart.destroy();
      if (error) {
        return reject(error);
      }
      return resolve(buffer);
    }, "image/png");
  });
```

If you do not need Promises then you can simply return the canvas.toBuffer() or canvas.toDataURL() data. Also, if you are using Typescript, I have had a bear of a time getting the Chart constructor to recognize the ctx value. I finally gave up and strong armed the typing:

```
const chart = new Chart(ctx as unknown as ChartItem, configuration);
```